# list directories that dont have certain list of files.

Tags: bash

I want to do a basic loop over a directory. It has a known set of subdirectories. Each of these is meant to have a list of files with the same name (file1, file2 ... file6). For those that have all 6, I want to rerun the process that creates them for those particular directories. What's the easiest way of getting a lsit of the directories that dont have the 6 files?

```
 for file in $oDir/* ; do
 find which dont have ALL 6 files [file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, file6]
 done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob  ## Do not allow presenting the pattern if no file is found.

for dir in "$oDir"/*; do
    [[ -d $dir ]] || continue  ## Skip those that aren't directories.
    files=("$dir"/file[1-6])   ## Match those files.
    if [[ ${#files[@]} -ne 6 ]]; then
        # This directory has at least one of those 6 files missing.
        # Do something.
        :
    fi
done
```

Make sure you run the script as bash. Either run it as `./script.sh` (header-based) or `bash script.sh`.

Comment: I think OP is trying to tell if one or more of the 6 is missing, not if there is an extra file... not sure, though.

Comment: oDir has a few subdirectories. I want to check each of these. Those that dont have the 6 files i want, i want to work on. All of them will have some other files that i dont care about at this stage.

Comment: while i like to think id have figured out how to do this eventually, thank you for going to the effort of showing me how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something along the lines of

```
if [ $(ls file* | wc -l) -ne 6 ]; then ...
```